# How to get a report with dynamic dates as columns in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

How to get a report with dynamic dates as columns in T-SQL.

I was looking for a piece of code like this like crazy.

Hope it will help other people.

If anyone knows any better solution please post.

```
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[' + convert(nvarchar(12), data, 103) + ']',
'[' + convert(nvarchar(12), data, 103)+ ']')
FROM Item
GROUP BY data
--print @columns


DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)

SET @query = '

;WITH G1 As
(
select id_item, convert(nvarchar(12), data, 103) as data, COUNT(*) as numar
from Item
group by id_item, data

)

SELECT *
FROM G1
PIVOT
(
sum(numar)
FOR [data]
IN (' + @columns + ')
) AS G2
'
print @query
EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem with your example?

Comment: Not really a problem, but I had a hard time getting a script example such as that. I hope it hepls anyone else. I just like to share. :)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of comments on the example in your question.

Use `QUOTENAME` rather than concatenating the square brackets yourself. This will deal correctly with any `]` characters in the data.

You seem to be mixing `nvarchar` and `varchar`. Declare the dynamic SQL variables as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` (or `NVARCHAR(4000)` if targeting SQL Server 2000) not `VARCHAR(8000)`. This will mean that your query works correctly with Unicode data and is a generally more secure practice when concatenating dynamic SQL.

(Just to add an example of why I say this is more secure)

```
create table #t (a int, b char(1));

DECLARE @querystring varchar(max)
DECLARE @nquerystring nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @userinput nvarchar(100) = N'ʼ;Drop Table #t--'

IF @userinput LIKE '%''%'
        BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Possible SQL injection',16,1)
        RETURN
        END


SET @nquerystring = 'select * from #t where b = ''' + @userinput + ''''


exec (@nquerystring)

select OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') /*NOT NULL, Still There*/

SET @querystring = @nquerystring /*ʼ nchar(700) gets silently converted to a regular ' character*/

exec (@querystring)

select OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') /*NULL, Table Dropped*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I shall take it into consideration.

But I don't use direct UserInput, but validated DateTime fields.

Comment: @Meltdown - Other people might come across this code (that's why you posted it isn't it?) and use it in situations where that doesn't apply though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a static version (from a coleague):

```
with c as (
    select
        p.id_doc,
        p.id_usr,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, p.created_at, getdate()) as date_diff
    from Document p
    where 1 = 1 
), p as (
    select
        pvt.id_usr,
        [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]
    from c
    PIVOT (COUNT(c.id_doc) FOR c.date_diff IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9])) AS pvt
)
select
    u.username,
    u.name,
    [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9],
    y.nr,
    y.total_money
from p
inner join Users u on u.id_usr = p.id_usr
cross apply (
    select
        COUNT(1) as nr,
        SUM(premium) as total_money
    from Document z
    where z.id_usr = p.id_usr
) as y
order by nr desc
```